# Music Mode what mode is song in?

Tags: theory, scales, jazz, blues

I have a Blues solo to analyse, the key is G major and it makes use of blue notes such as B flat and F natural, does anyone know what 'mode' the song is in

Comment: Hi, and welcome. There's nowhere near enough information here to elicit a good answer. Chances are it's not in a mode.

Comment: the solo//melody starts on the tonic but uses accidentals that don't correspond with the key signature

Comment: That's blues for you!

Comment: The blues uses the blues scale often, which doesn't match any modes.

Answer (score 2):

Players don't generally think of modes while playing the blues.  It's just not inherent to the style.  But, blues is very much improvised over with the minor, or major pentatonic as a basis, and then additional notes are thrown in.  As a tip, one way of looking at modes, are that there are 3 major, 3 minor, and one diminished. The 3 major modes have the major pentatoic in them (plus 2 different "extras").  The 3 minor modes have the minor pentatonic in them (plus 2 different "extras").  I mention this because modal players tend to use a lot more stepwise action, and blues players have a greater sense of hierarchy in their note selection (end on tonic, hang on the fifth, etc)

Comment: Maybe barrelhouse blues players stick to pentatonic scales, but jazz blues uses all kinds of non-pentatonic material. Come to think of it, Robben Ford plays diminished scales all over the place.

Comment: All blues is based off the pentatonic scales.  With additional notes, diminished is supported, even for the tonic chord.  Since blues often uses dominant 7th chords, a diminished substitution is appropriate for each in context.  The pentatonic is not low brow as implied, nor is it a prison that you can't hit notes outside of.

Comment: "All blues is based off the pentatonic scales" -- well, that just isn't true. And I never implied that pentatonic is lowbrow, or that you couldn't use other notes. Merely pointing out that pentatonic scales are not always the basis from which players operate. There are an awful lot of varieties of the blues these days, you know....

Comment: BTW, no need to think of diminished scales as substitutions here. You can play the Half-Whole Diminished scale over alt chords (or the alt scale, for that matter), and alt chords are straight-up dominant 7th chords.